# Comparison between WPF MVVM and ASP MVC applications relative to time's estimation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, mvvm

Maybe my question will be weird :
We have an application which consists :

1. Create a database
2. adding required  UI to handle crud operations for some database table
3. All the text zone are rich ie it allows us to put some text, change text's style(font,size,...), import pdf document and import or create schemas.
4. Visualize PDF file's content in the UI

It seems for me that the last two features are the most difficult. We have to choose between `WPF with MVVM design pattern` and `Asp.Net MVC` application. We have to choose which offers the lowest time's estimation.The team's members have the same experience with the two choices.

These are our, me and my collegue, points of view:

**My Collegue point of view (for WPF with MVVM)**

1. We have to choose WPF because `Always` the time estimation for a desktop application is lowest than a web application.
2. If we choose web application, we will spend a lot of time to make it compatible with **IE** browser and we have to add some **Javascript** snippet

**My Opinion (for Asp.net MVC)**

3. The comparison between Web application time's estimation an desktop time's estimation depends from the project itself. I disagree with him for the first point
4. In this project, we have UI which perform crud operations, I think the scaffolding features of asp.net mvc plateform can help us to reduce the time of developpement.
5. The feature of `Model Binding` can help us in the quick generation of interfaces

I need to know who is right? What is the best choice for this project?

Thanks,

Comment: Who could possibly tell?  Depends on so many factors, not just "javascript snippet".

Comment: @Will : thanks for your reply, but can you elaborate more your idea as an answer. Besides, the deployment ,hosting and creation of setup issues are not problem for us.So I just need a comparison of application developping time

Comment: I will choose ASP.NET MVC. It will give a hope, that solution will be alive a more time than WPF realization, web solution will give you much more users. Otherwise, if you are not very familiar with js frameworks, better choose WPF solution and do it without any problems. WPF is very good, but it's only desktop (of course if you don't want create app on fresh UAP). So, I thinks estimating time depends only on your possibilities working with extra tools. Oh, I forgot, you shouldn't blind yourself, scaffolding features of asp.net mvc will not give you a much more development time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem to be a fairly opinionated question with no absolute answer. However.

1. Compatible with IE browser is hardly a concern anymore. ie6 is not a dominate browser anymore and if your clients are using it, you got to ask yourself why. With libraries like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), [htmlShiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), jquery, bootstrap etc , it is rarely a major problem unless you are on the cutting edge.
2. Adding javascript libraries is non trivial, and should not be a concern, if anything it is a "pro" for web development , because there are so many to choose from compared to a lesser degree with WPF and its components.
3. The time estimation between the two really comes down to how well the developers know html/css/javascript vs xaml. You might be interested to know that there is an extension for visual studio that converts xaml to css/html . [CSHTML5](http://cshtml5.com/press-releases/2014-09-29-CSharp-Xaml-For-Html5-beta1-released.aspx)
4. The scaffolding is a handy feature. But they are fairly basic in their default form. To create your own is fairly easy , but there are some nuances to get use to when writing t4 templates especially if you are using viewmodels / parialviews or anything outside of a standard model to view concept. There is also an extension to help with the formatting . [Devart t4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a42a8538-8d6e-491b-8097-5a8a00174d37)
5. WPF also has model binding. On that note. Asp mvc is an mvc framework right. However the model passed to the view is not an observable , so technically is it not a *pure mvc framework. It does use viewmodels quite heavily, and so can be considered a mv(vm)c which is actually quite similar to WPF MVVM . A point should be given to WPF here. Its binding is really easy to use and layered on xaml means you are very free to play around with interactivity and a much better UX feel. [WPF morden UI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) is a very nice starting point for layout if you havnt checked it out
6. I think the main concern should be.

**How do you want your users to consume the application?** Do you want them to quickly be able to open the browser and use the app, or do you want them to download the application and then use it, knowing that all the users are competent enough to download and install without any problems.

**Are any of your users going to be on mac, or linux?** Because then you have to consider using the [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/) if you develop in WPF to accommodate those users.

**Would you want you clients to be able to use the application offline?** Using localstorage on the browser can help with offline consumption, but not to the usability extent of WPF. Using WPF also allows you to plugin deeper into windows , which could be very handy if you want to take advantage of extendable features that the windows operating system allows. Ie plugging into outlook to send the pdf's

7. The kicker. If you decide to use Asp mvc then why not just use asp web api. That way you can build the services in a web format and just push the data where you need it. You can have a browser based option and a WPF option , with most of the work for both only tending towards interface development. So you have the best of both worlds without much extra effort. This will also allow for a fairly straight development process if you decide to create a phone app with phonegap. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbZMWTizaO4) is a cool intro video into webapi with a browser and WPF solution.

I know in most of my cases i just get told what to use, sometimes even by the client. So enjoy the research , not all of us get to weight out the pros and cons.